# Rails Join with Hash multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

i'm trying to do a query which returns all the name of users who have animals where it's tipo is 'Cachorro'

So i have 3 tables

```
User
has_many :animals

attribute sample
t.string :name

Animal 
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :animals

attribute samples
user_id
tipo_id

Tipo
has_many :animals

attribute sample
tipo_animal
```

So far i didn't figured out how sould i do structure this query inside console:

```
User.joins(:animals, :tipo).where(animals.tipo.tipo_animal: 'Cachorro')
```

doesn't work, any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the bare words `animals.tipo.tipo_animal` in Ruby. That makes no sense to Ruby, those aren't things which are defined in the current scope.

You need to give ActiveRecord a *string* containing that column name:

```
...where("animals.tipo.tipo_animal" => 'Cachorro')
```

Comment: Ty.

Can you help me with another issue?

i have to multiply by 3 the value of a column

like 

1 User have many animals, animals have it's mensal_cost, so i need to get this mensal cost and multiply by 3 

trying something like this: 

    Animal.where(user_id).sum('3 * mensal_cost')  

but couldn't go further :(

Comment: @h3ll If you have another question, just [ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38963829/rails-multiplying-value-of-af-column-using-activerecord  

ty again :)