# Rails Multiplying value of afcolumn using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, console

I want to multiply a value of an specific column considering the user id.

Assume I have a table `users` with user 1 (id 1) and user 2 (id 2), and a table `animals` which has `name` and `mensal_cost`.

Ok, then I added two animals for user 1 (id 1) and 1 animal for user 2 (id 2)

I want to know how I can using `ActiveRecord` calculates the `mensal_cost` income after 3 months increasing the same base value, it means I have to multiply the actual value by 3.

I'm trying something like this:

```
Animal.where(user_id: ?).sum('3*mensal_cost')
```

Since I don't know how many users can exist, I must write a call which will list for each user id the amount after 3 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you nearly had it on your own - just the minor details can be like this:

```
user_ids = [id1, id2]
full_sum = 3 * Animal.where(:user_id => user_ids).sum(:mensal_cost)
```

Note: don't forget you can multiply by three after summing and it'll be the same as summing each one multiplied by 3 eg

(3 * 2) + (3 * 3) + (3 * 4) == 3 * (2 + 3 + 4)

or you can iterate through the users to get their individual sums like so:

```
mensal_sums = {}
user_ids = [id1, id2]
user_ids.each do |user_id|
   mensal_sums[user_id] = 3 * Animal.where(:user_id => user_id).sum(:mensal_cost)
end

puts mensal_sums
=> {id1 => 63, id2 => 27}
```

EDIT
and one where you want the user name as well:

```
mensal_sums = {}
users = User.find([id1, id2])
users.each do |user|
   mensal_sums[user.id] = {:user_name => user.name,
                           :sum => (3 * user.animals.sum(:mensal_cost)) }
end

puts mensal_sums
=> {id1 => {:user_name => "Bob Jones", :sum => 63},
    id2 => {:user_name => "cJane Brown", :sum =>27}
   }
```

Comment: Taryn, fisrt of all, thank you for your answer.  But this way will giv me the total of mensal_cost from all users multiplied by 3.  What i really needs is to see like:  id1 mensal_cost * 3  = 300, id2 mensal_cost * 3 = 700...

Comment: ah cool. yeah I see what you mean. You can iterate through the array of users to build it... there's probably a "group by" way of doing it in one query, but the iteration way will work well enough. i'll add an example.

Comment: Great :), your example probab will help me a lot because now i need to get the user name (with is in user table) for each user id.  

I think i probab need to do something like User.joins(:animals)....here i don't know how to structure a hash, i already read but didn't get it :(

Comment: sure - how about I add a bit about how to pull out the user and get the animals from them

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out the solution:

```
Animal.group('user_id').sum('3*mensal_cost')
```

the group was the key :D